# Prevent adding duplicate values in array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am running this code and calling the ajax request 20 times. I want to add the ajax response into an array if same record is not already present inside the array. I am doing this way but it isadding duplicate data as well. What I am doing wrong in this one?
I tried using indexOf also but that also not seem to be working

Is there any way I can skip the objects with same id everytime loop runs?

For example if i get api response with CID 28 and again if CID 28 comes i skip that object from adding to array.

```js
for(let i = 0; i< 20; i++){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/bin/adp/rest_api_response.megtile.json",
                    method: "POST",
                    "data": { "session": sessionID, "WIN_NBR": win, "local_time": localT.toString(), "network": "on" },
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {

                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                        urls = data.btn_link;
                        var tmp_thumbnail = "url('" + data.image + "')"
                        thumbnails = tmp_thumbnail;
                        descriptions = data.banner_text;
                        btn_txt = data.btn_text;
                        titles = data.banner_title;
                        cid = data.CID;

                        console.log("datttt",arr)
                        console.log("dddd",data)
                        if (arr.includes(data) === false) {
                            arr.push(data);                        
                        }
                        
                    }
                });
            }
```

```js
API Response
{
    "CID": "CID28",
    "btn_link": "https://one.xyz.com",
    "btn_text": "Visit page",
    "campaign_title": "RFL Talkspace",
    "banner_text": "Talk to a licensed, professional therapist. ",
    "banner_title": "Talking about it can help.",
    "image": "/content/dam/us-wire-wm1/images/me@/campaigns/campaigns-2021/may/talkspace.png",
    "link": "",
    "request_ID": "fa9a925b-f882-410-558-761e179eb227"
}

Duplicate API response

{
    "CID": "CID28",
    "btn_link": "https://one.xyz.com",
    "btn_text": "Visit page",
    "campaign_title": "RFL Talkspace",
    "banner_text": "Talk to a licensed, professional therapist. ",
    "banner_title": "Talking about it can help.",
    "image": "/content/dam/us-wire-wm1/images/me@/campaigns/campaigns-2021/may/talkspace.png",
    "link": "",
    "request_ID": "fa9a925b-f882-410-558-761e179eb227"
}

API another response
{
    "CID": "CID3",
    "btn_link": "https://get.com/automatic",
    "btn_text": "Learn more",
    "campaign_title": "Even App",
    "banner_text": "",
    "banner_title": "Get automatic access to your earned wages every week",
    "image": "/content/uswire/en_us/me/campaigns/even-app/jcr:content/par/hero_v2_copy_cpy.g.jpeg",
    "link": "",
    "request_ID": "ae5e5396-0317-4ec8-b7b1-9f0deef5cd"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to convert the `data` into a string and then push it to the array? 
Convert the incoming `data` object into a string and then using the arr.includes function to check if the incoming `data` exists in the arr.

Comment: @decpk Isnt it the same thing?

Comment: @TheKNVB ys i tried it, it also dint work

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to demonstrate what I say:

```js
let a={
    "CID": "CID28",
    "btn_link": "https://one.xyz.com",
    "btn_text": "Visit page",
    "campaign_title": "RFL Talkspace",
    "banner_text": "Talk to a licensed, professional therapist. ",
    "banner_title": "Talking about it can help.",
    "image": "/content/dam/us-wire-wm1/images/me@/campaigns/campaigns-2021/may/talkspace.png",
    "link": "",
    "request_ID": "fa9a925b-f882-410-558-761e179eb227"
};
let b={
    "CID": "CID28",
    "btn_link": "https://one.xyz.com",
    "btn_text": "Visit page",
    "campaign_title": "RFL Talkspace",
    "banner_text": "Talk to a licensed, professional therapist. ",
    "banner_title": "Talking about it can help.",
    "image": "/content/dam/us-wire-wm1/images/me@/campaigns/campaigns-2021/may/talkspace.png",
    "link": "",
    "request_ID": "fa9a925b-f882-410-558-761e179eb227"
};
let arr=[JSON.stringify(a)];
let arr1=[a];
console.log("using the stringify method:"+arr.includes(JSON.stringify(b)));
console.log("without using the stringify method:"+arr1.includes(b));
```

Comment: So I am doing this in every iteration, not working for me 
                        let x = JSON.stringify(data)
                        console.log("xx",x)
                        if (!arr.includes(x)) {
                            arr.push(x);                        
                        }

Comment: Can you post the content of the duplicate `data` object?

Comment: Its same ------------"CID": "CID28",
    "btn_link": "https://one.xyz.com",
    "btn_text": "Visit page",
    "campaign_title": "RFL Talkspace",
    "banner_text": "Talk to a licensed, professional therapist. ",
    "banner_title": "Talking about it can help.",
    "image": "/content/dam/us-wire-wm1/images/me@/campaigns/campaigns-2021/may/talkspace.png",
    "link": "",
    "request_ID": "fa9a925b-f882-410-558-761e179eb227"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to search an Object inside an Array of Objects use a custom function for object comparison. My way of implementation is added below.

```js
const responseObj = {
  "CID": "CID28",
  "btn_link": "https://one.xyz.com",
  "btn_text": "Visit page",
  "campaign_title": "RFL Talkspace",
  "banner_text": "Talk to a licensed, professional therapist. ",
  "banner_title": "Talking about it can help.",
  "image": "/content/dam/us-wire-wm1/images/me@/campaigns/campaigns-2021/may/talkspace.png",
  "link": "",
  "request_ID": "fa9a925b-f882-410-558-761e179eb227"
};
const responseArr = [];
responseArr.push(responseObj);
const responseObjNew = { ...responseObj };

// Using Includes method
console.log('Using array.includes', responseArr.includes(responseObjNew));

// Using Custom defined function
console.log('Using custom functon', containsObject(responseObjNew, responseArr));

// Updating Object
responseObjNew.CID = "CID13";

// Checking with updated object
console.log('Using custom functon', containsObject(responseObjNew, responseArr));

function containsObject(obj, list) {
  var isFound;
  for (let index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
    isFound = compareObjects(obj, list[index]);
    if(isFound) {
      // Matching Object Found: EXIT
      index = list.length;
    }
  }
  return isFound;
}
function compareObjects(obj1, obj2) {
  var isMatch = Object.keys(obj1).length === Object.keys(obj2).length;
    if (isMatch) {
      Object.keys(obj1).forEach((key) => {
        isMatch = isMatch && obj1[key] === obj2[key]
      })
    }
    return isMatch
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If, as you already mentioned yourself, the "same" response can be recognised by having the same `id` then you can simplify the comparison by using an object instead of an array to hold the  data received from your AJAX calls:

```
// somewhere at the top:
var obj={}; // global variable

// then, within your AJAX-related code:
// ...
cid = data.CID

if (!obj[cid]) obj[cid]=data;
```

If you want to access the results as an array you can always extract it from `obj` by doing

```
arr = Object.values(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just process the array after it's been created?

```
  const people = [
     { id: 1, firstName: "John", secondName: "Smith"}
     { id: 7, firstName: "Jack", secondName: "Foster"},
     { id: 7, firstName: "Jack", secondName: "Foster"},
     { id: 7, firstName: "Jack", secondName: "Foster"}
];
```

Then just use [helprjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helprjs) to solve the issue for you.

```
removeDuplicates(people, "id");
// [{ id: 1, firstName: "John", secondName: "Smith"}]
```

Try the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/removeduplicates-do4oe?file=/src/App.js:879-925) here